# how to pass comment and comment id of php database loop to jquery then back to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i have a code on a comment system where the id of the looped image is the value of the submit button then the textarea contains the comment. so i want to pass the comment and its id to Jquery and Ajax which will return it to PHP page for validation, the code below runs but it only submit the comment for the first image of the loop but submits only the id for other image loops without the comment itself. here is my code:

jquery and Ajax code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".comment1").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var text1 = $("#comment1").val();
            var submit1 = $(this).val();
            $("body").load("personal.php",{
                comment: text1,
                commentbtn: submit1
            });
        });  
    });
</script>
```

main part of PHP code:

```
<?php
    $go="SELECT * FROM images WHERE images.title='$my_course' &&  images.type!='tutorials'";        
    $gresult= mysqli_query($conn, $go);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($gresult) > 0){
        while($frow= mysqli_fetch_assoc($gresult)){
            $imggd=$frow['id'];
            echo"<textarea type='text' name='comment' id='comment1'   placeholder='write...'>"
                ."</textarea>"
                ."<button type='submit' name='commentbtn'  class='comment1' id='$imggd' value='$imggd'>"
                ."<span class='fab fa-telegram-plane' id='updd'>"
                ."</span>"
                ."</button>"
                ."</div>"
                ."<br/>";
        }
    }
?>
```

in the code above the textarea id is the #comment1 while the submit button class is .comment1. only the id is submitted forthe images except for the first item that runs correctly.  please i really need help thank you. In case I didn't place my questions well forgive me i am just new here.

Comment: Hi, maybe u can try name= "comment[]"
or u will name to have name with a index. if u are using the same "name" it will replace the value.

Comment: Your are looping an id that equals "comment1" in your textarea...  and an id is supposed to be unique. As Kimberlee said... try name="comment[]"

Comment: sorry it didn't work out

Comment: please i am really stuck on this. can anyone else provide me a working answer

Comment: well, since no body cared to give me a working answer i have gotten a way of doing it in case you want to know then chat me up